# Click an object and show another - simple jQuery snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple click and show snippet which needs a bit of modifying. The behavior that I am striving for is when I click on another LI element, to hide the other grey boxes from the other LI objects. Also, I need it to hide all the grey boxes when I click on the body of the document (e.g. > outside of the UL container).

Here is some sample code:

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#serviceList').find('.modal.active').removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.modal').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Here is a [**fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/xvopdkf8/)

I am having a bit of a hassle reaching the desired effect. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xvopdkf8/4/

You missed giving `id` to your `UL` element as `<ul id="serviceList">`

Modified JS code is as follows:

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#serviceList').find('.modal.active').removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.modal').toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.closest("#serviceList").length == 0)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#serviceList').find('.modal.active').removeClass('active');
    }
    else
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the containing div that is wrapping around the UL. The div has an id of "serviceList". This works exactly the way I need it to. Thank You very much!

Comment: Just one more little thing. How can I make the modal dissapear when I click inside it?

Comment: @Sqnkov - please have a look at newer fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xvopdkf8/7/. Changed the first `click` event too; to suit your requirement.

Comment: Yes, but there is a small problem, you are targeting the H2 tag, and I need it to open clicking on the whole LI element. When I remove the H2 addressed in the script it just toggles over and over again.

Comment: I managed to do a workaround for this issue, I just placed the IMG inside the h2 tag. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$('html').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal').removeClass('active');
});
$('.openModal').on('click', function (e) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.modal').removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.modal').toggleClass('active');
});`
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvopdkf8/3/)

Comment: Nothing happens in the fiddle :/

Comment: Strange, I have rechecked its working fine, have you clicked on the text?

Answer (score 0):

modifying your JS it Works

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().find('.modal.active').toggleClass('active');// or use removeClass
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.modal').toggleClass('active');
});
```

**Note: I assume that the list element container has modals**

Comment: Yes, there are modals inside each LI element, but this code does the exact same thing as my snippet :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function (e) {
        $('ul li').find('.modal.active').removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('.modal').toggleClass('active');
    });
```